# PHP: Using preg_split to split on empty lines

Tags: php, preg-split

I would like to split a multi-line string using using an empty line as a delimiter.

For example:

```
apple
aardvark
accordion

banana
bilby
banjo

cherry
cockatoo
cello
```

should give me results like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
aardvark
accordion
[2] => banana
bilby
banjo
[3] => cherry
cockatoo
cello
```

I have tried the following:

```
$data=preg_split('/^$/m',$data);
```

but I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
aardvark
accordion

    [1] => 
banana
bilby
banjo

    [2] => 
cherry
cockatoo
cello
)
```

That is, the results appear to include the leading and trailing empty line.

I have tried `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`, but that only makes it worse: the result is a single string.

What should I do to split a string by empty lines?

Comment: `$data = preg_split('/\n{2,}/',$data);`

Comment: the regex `/-/` matches dashes, there's no dashes here.

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry, I copied the wrong expression for testing. The regular expression I really used is: `/^$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the simple explode() function?

```
$str = "apple
aardvark
accordion

banana
bilby
banjo

cherry
cockatoo
cello" ;

 $arr = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, $str);

Var_dump ($arr);
```

Output:

```
 array(3) {
 [0]=>
 string(24) "apple
 aardvark
 accordion"
 [1]=>
 string(18) "banana
 bilby
 banjo"
 [2]=>
 string(21) "cherry
cockatoo
cello"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/98CV8

Comment: Thanks. A good alternative solution which worked well. I’m still wondering why the other didn’t work.